# Cannot Hide/Supress OOB Model-Driven Apps (Customer Service Hub, Sales Hub, etc)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I am trying to suppress or hide the OOB model-driven apps from all users except System Admins.  I have navigated to Settings -> my Apps -> App (ellipses) -> Manage Roles and removed all roles except admin and customizer.
I have assigned my test user a single role, the role has "Read" permission on Model-driven App in Security Role -> Customization tab.  If I remove read permission the user see NO model-driven Apps, with Read permission the user sees ALL model-driven app, even though roles are restricted.

Any guidance would be much obliged.

[image: Screenshot of limited role permissions]

[image: Custom Security Role has read permissions on "Model-Driven App" entity]

Comment: Try incognito window ? i might be cached

Answer (score 1):

The security on what Apps are visible to Users are not done in the security role directly.

You have to go to your app and select security roles which can than see the app.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/share-model-driven-app